# What does "more happy than surprised" mean, and why not use "happier than"?

Tags: adjectives, comparative-constructions

Please tell me why people use comparative in this sentence. It is very strange to me.

> The parents were **more happy than surprised** at the study result of their son.

Why don't they use "happier than surprised"?

Answer (score 3):

Here you're comparing two descriptions, *happy*  and *surprised*, saying one is more suitable or accurate than another.
 *-er* is not used in such cases.

> He's more lazy than stupid. (NOT He's lazier than stupid)

Practical English Usage, Swan, p. 114